# Converting xml to txt in python

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I am using python 3.6 and want to convert/write some information from my .x81-file (which looks just like xml) to a .txt-file.

I keep on getting "a bytes-like object is required, not 'ElementTree'" problem. But I can not find a solution online.

Here is my code:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

xmlstr = ET.parse('06 MSR Technik.x81')
GAEB = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)

for GAEB in list(Award):
    Ordnungszahl = Award.find('RNoPart').text
    Pos = Award.find('Qty').text
    text = Award.find('Description').text

    print('Ordnungszahl: %s; Pos: %s; text: %s' % (Ordnungszahl, Pos, text))
```

And here is the problem:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/Amy_6/Desktop/Uni/Python/Probeprojekt/XML to TXT/XmlToTxt.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/Amy_6/Desktop/Uni/Python/Probeprojekt/XML to TXT/XmlToTxt.py", line 4, in <module>
       GAEB = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1314, in XML
       parser.feed(text)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'ElementTree'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

according to you code, `ET.parse()` has already read the xml file and converted to the `Element`. You don’t need to use `ET.fromstring()` to create `Element` again.

`fromestring()` parses XML from a string directly into an `Element`. For example, `ET.fromstring('<?xml?......>')`

Comment: So if i understood you right i had to edit my code to this: `from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

xmlstr = ET.parse('06 MSR Technik.x81')

for Award in list(xmlstr):` but then it tells me `TypeError: 'ElementTree' object is not iterable`  what am i doing wrong ?